# jquery ajax call works only on localhost

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

i m using jquery ajax to get data from an asp.net back end method like this:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Live/Live.aspx/GetViews") %>',
    content: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{ 'Altid' : '" + GetAltId() + "' }",
    success: function (msg) {
        $("#backEndCount").text(msg.d);
    },
    fail: function (msg) {
        $("#backEndCount").text(msg.d);
    }
});
```

and the back end method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetViews(int Altid) 
{
    return Live.count(Altid);
}
```

this call works fine locally, but on the remote service i get the page html as a response instead of the normal response which is the "d".

what is the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check two main things:

1. Make sure asp.net is supported on the server (try to run any aspx page and make sure it is behaving normally)
2. Make sure the path `'<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Live/Live.aspx/GetViews") %>'` is correct online (try the full path for testing)

Comment: i believe that asp.net is supported as the rest of the site is behaving as it should, as for the full path according to firebug it's requesting the right path.

Comment: ok, are you sure jquery is running normally online? have you uploaded all your files?

Comment: can you try putting the url in this format: url: "mypage.aspx/mymethod" without ResolveUrl

Comment: @AliIssa - Updates and re uploaded jquery but the same issue still exists, tried changing the url without the ResolveUrl but with no luck.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - No other errors showing in firebug or fiddler

Comment: @AliIssa - it was a problem with the path, asp.net routing was interfering with it. thanks